# Own Custom Field Plugin - Multiple Inputs

Tags: custom-field, fields

I am currently creating a custom field plugin for Joomla! I am now faced with the task / problem that the user needs more than just one field when adding the information. In detail it is so that it is a map plugin and the user can enter the coordinates in a field and set the label and the description (field type text & textarea) for the marker popup. So my plugin should not only be able to output one field type text in the backend but two text fields and a textarea.

I already tried to generate the fields and return them comma-separated or in an array (hoping this application scenario exists) which unfortunately failed.

most of the work for this plugin is done but is there a way to have multiple fields rendered?
i know it is a custom field plugin not a custom field**s** plugin, but maybe...

```
class PlgFieldsPluginName extends FieldsPlugin{
protected $hint = '46.856112,9.517915';

public function onCustomFieldsPrepareDom($field, DOMElement $parent, JForm $form)
{
    $coordsField = parent::onCustomFieldsPrepareDom($field, $parent, $form);
    if (!$coordsField)
    {
        return $coordsField;
    };

    $coordsField->setAttribute('hint', $this->hint);
    $coordsField->setAttribute('description', JText::_('NX_BINGMP_VALUE_DESC'));
    

    return $coordsField;
}
}
```

As a completion: I am talking effectively about the area when you enter  data in an article field. Not about the plugin parameters or the field parameters that are solved via XML.

**UPDATE:**
As mentioned in the comments I tried to extend the Subbform Field. Unfortunately this leads to the following error:

```
     0 Class 'JFormFieldSubform' not found
```

Code adjusted as follows:

```
protected $hint = '46.856112,9.517915';

public function onCustomFieldsPrepareDom($field, DOMElement $parent, JForm $form)
{
    $coordsField = parent::onCustomFieldsPrepareDom($field, $parent, $form);
    if (!$coordsField)
    {
        return $coordsField;
    };

    $coordsField->setAttribute('repeatable', 'false');
    $coordsField->setAttribute('formsource', '/plugins/fields/pluginname/fields/config.xml');
    $coordsField->setAttribute('description', JText::_('NX_BINGMP_VALUE_DESC'));


    return $coordsField;
}
```

$coordsField should now be of type subform...

My pluginname.php in fields folder looks like this:

```
class JFormFieldPluginname extends JFormFieldSubform
{
public $type = 'pluginname';
}
```

So after some research I found this thread that confirmed my half-knowledge - There is no Subform Field as a Custom Field in Joomla 3:

[Github](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/22446)

Comment: Have you tried using Subform?

Comment: subform? is it available in j3.x?

Comment: It is available. Inspect the code of `Fields - Repeatable` plugin, it already uses Subform for a similar purpose.